# Minimum segment length in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro

I am working on a watershed mapping project and am having an issue with my main stream stem disappearing after running a tool on the layer. The only lead I have as to why this is happening is a short segments message when running check geometry on previous layers before the stream gets deleted. According to [ESRI](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/validating-data/invalid-geometry.htm), this occurs when "some segments are shorter than allowed by the system units of the spatial reference associated with the geometry." I'm not sure what this means, do coordinate systems include a minimum allowable length? If so I haven't been able to find it. The resolution of my spatial reference is 0.0003281 US Survey Feet and the tolerance is 0.002382 Survey Feet. I converted my stream polygon to polylines and split them at vertices to see what the shortest segment was, and it is 0.023622 US Survey Feet.

I found an [ESRI article](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/data-reviewer/data-management/invalid-geometry-check-explained/#:%7E:text=This%20occurs%20when%20the%20vertices%20in%20a%20polyline%20or%20polygon%20boundary%20are%20too%20close%3B%20but%C2%A0still%20are%20within%20the%20database%E2%80%99s%20XY%20tolerance.) that elaborates on short segments:

> This occurs when the vertices in a polyline or polygon boundary are
> too close; but still are within the database’s XY tolerance.

I am still unclear on what defines "too close" if not the XY tolerance.

Comment: Please provide a link to the article that you’re quoting from.

Comment: What tool are you running on the layer?